# How do you solve apt-get update error "Could not resolve"?

Tags: 14.04, apt, repository, nginx, vps

I just purchased server space with a VPS provider. The first thing I wanted to do is install the lastest version of Nginx. I followed the official instructions from Nginx as described [here](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html). Everything went smoothly until I ran `sudo apt-get update`. For some reason, it seems all the respositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` update correctly except the ones for Nginx that I have added manually.

I have a test server on my LAN which I setup exactly the same as the this virtual private server, so I know the configuration works.

I am relatively new to all this, I have no idea what may be causing this, and I could not find anyone online that had the same issue, but I tried these diagnostic steps from what I could find:

Removed all nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and added only Google's `8.8.8.8` - did not solve the problem and then all repositories had errors when I ran `sudo apt-get update`

Anytime I try to `ping` anything, the output is always `connect: Network is unreachable`

but if I run `host www.google.com`, for instance, I get this output:

```
www.google.com has address 74.125.28.147
www.google.com has address 74.125.28.99
www.google.com has address 74.125.28.103
www.google.com has address 74.125.28.104
www.google.com has address 74.125.28.105
www.google.com has address 74.125.28.106
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::93
```

This is the output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err http://nginx.org trusty InRelease

Err http://nginx.org trusty Release.gpg                                 
  Could not resolve 'nginx.org'
Ign http://mirrors.gandi.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://mirrors.gandi.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://mirrors.gandi.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.gandi.net trusty/main amd64 Packages              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease           
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63.5 kB]    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://mirrors.gandi.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release          
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [80.6 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release             
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [2061 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [24.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2335 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [268 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                 
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8875 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [103 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en             
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3680 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en 
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [202 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [2564 B]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [117 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5161 B]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [516 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [9238 B]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [279 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [12.0 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Fetched 1766 kB in 9s (189 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'nginx.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

these are the lines I added to the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` for Nginx:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
```

Comment: I just spun an instance of Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and was able to setup nginx as specified at http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html. The only difference I did was that I logged in as root and so didn't have to use the sudo prefix (already being root). Try it yourself (login as root) and check. Also, I didn't change the /etc/resolv.conf. Suggest you should leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the virtual private server only had an IPv6 interface and the location of the official Nginx package does not support IPv6 as of when this question was asked.

The hosting company which I use offers IPv6 interfaces for free, and charges extra if you would like an IPv4 interface (since IPv4 addresses are reaching unavailability, it is their attempt to conserve them).

The solution was simply paying for the IPv4 interface. Updating works flawlessly after implementing an IPv4 interface.